# Calculating ICC for random-effects logistic regression

Tags: logistic, lme4-nlme, glmm

I'm running a logistic regression model in the form:

```
lmer(response~1+(1|site), family=binomial, REML = FALSE)
```

Normally I would calculate the ICC from the intercept and residual variances, but the summary of the model doesn't include residual variance.  How do I calculate this?

Comment: Why are you calculating the ICC?

Comment: In order to test the assumption that ordinary logistic regression is not valid for these data, as evidence that I should be using GLMM.  I found an equation: ICClogit=intercept variance^2/(intercept variance^2+pi^2/3).  Does this seem reasonable?

Comment: You're using the full maximum likelihood approach. Can't you do a likelihood ratio test with 1 degree of freedom against the fixed effects model?

Comment: @Megan: You are right. In practice, Zeger et al. (1988) suggests $(15/16)^2\pi^2/3$ works better than $\pi^2/3$ as residual variance for logistic regression models, though the two are very close. See S. L. Zeger, K. Y. Liang, and P. S. Albert. Models for longitudinal data: a generalized estimating equation approach. Biometrics, 44: 1049-1060 1988.

Comment: @Megan: It is ``intercept_variance / (intercept_variance + pi^2/3)`` -- so don't square the variance.

Comment: @Randel, I'm tempted to use the variant you (err, Zeger et al) suggest, but the paper is somewhat over my head. Can you point me to any more material about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `icc()`-function from the [sjstats-package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sjstats).

In the help-file `?sjstats::icc` you find a reference to the formula for mixed models with binary response:

> Wu S, Crespi CM, Wong WK. 2012. Comparison of methods for estimating
>   the intraclass correlation coefficient for binary responses in cancer
>   prevention cluster randomized trials. Contempory Clinical Trials 33:
>   869-880 (doi: 10.1016/j.cct.2012.05.004)

The residual deviance in logistic regression is fixed to `(pi ^ 2) / 3`.

Comment: Do you have a reference for this formula?

Comment: Do you mean me? Wasn't your comment initially at the OP posting?

Comment: @Jeanine- ICC citation: Moineddin, R., Matheson, F. I., & Glazier, R. H. (2007). A simulation study of sample size for multilevel logistic regression models. BMC Medical Research Methodology, 7, 34. https://doi.org/10.1186/1471-2288-7-34