# 0 value for between-cluster variance in hierarchical logistic regression

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, intraclass-correlation

I am analysing a dichotomous predicted variable for a cluster randomised trial.
The model is below. The predicted variable is binary and there are two measures, pre- and post-intervention. There is a categorical group factor (intervention vs control) and the clustering variable is pracID. The model looks like this:

```
mod4 <- glmer(irr_fu_therapy_intent_bin ~ group + irr_base_therapy_intent_bin + (1 | pracID), data = dfIntTher, family = binomial(link = "logit"))
```

and the output looks like this

```
Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 pracID (Intercept) 0        0       
Number of obs: 205, groups:  pracID, 20

Fixed effects:
                            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                   -1.536      0.495   -3.10   0.0019 ** 
groupintervention              1.238      0.544    2.27   0.0229 *  
irr_base_therapy_intent_bin    4.816      0.713    6.76  1.4e-11 ***
```

Is it normal to get a 0 value like this for the between-cluster variance? I am confident that the dataframe itself is sound, so if I were very confident with this I would just assume this means that there is no correlation between individuals in eahc cluster, however I have read that the between-cluster variance is not as straightforward to estimate in a hierarchical logistic regression. I need to calculate the ICC and from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62770/calculating-icc-for-random-effects-logistic-regression) I have learned how to derive the within-cluster component, but I am a very wary of 0 values.

Any advice on this or alternative methods for calculating the ICC would be much appreciated

Comment: They may just be very close to zero and rounded when printed. Have you tried extracting them and then examining them? Or plotting the random effects?