# glmer: how to test intra- and inter-individual variability of a variable on outcome

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, random-effects-model

I am an R beginner so I wish I could get some help with `glmer` model.

I have 165 subjects and each of them has been measured for drug concentration (continuous variable) and outcome (binary variable Y/N) for 14 days. Drug concentration and outcome data might vary within an individual on different days; while genotype (categorical, 3 groups) is fixed within an individual. I hypothesize drug concentration and genotype would affect outcome. Therefore, I aim to test the effect of intra- or inter-individual drug concentration variability, and genotype on outcome.

I have two models:

```
glmer1 <- glmer(outcome~genotype+drug concen+(1|patient ID), family="binomial", data=data1)

glmer2 <- glmer(outcome~genotype+drug concen+(drug concen|patient ID), family="binomial", data=data1)
```

My questions are: is `glmer1`  testing intra-individual drug concentration variability on outcome? And is `glmer2` testing inter-individual drug concentration variability on outcome? Or any sub-analysis to test my hypothesis?

For genotype, I know it's testing the genetic effects of inter-individual variability on outcome because each patient only has one fixed genotype. However, I don't know how it works for drug concentration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your first model:

```
glmer1 <- glmer(outcome ~ genotype + drug_concen+(1|patient_ID), family="binomial", data=data1)
```

here you modelling the association of `genotype` and `drug_concen` on `outcome`, on a patient, while adjusting for the clustering effect of repeated observations withing patients (which may lead to correlated observations on the same patient). The fixed effects coefficients tell you the change in `outcome` associated with a change in either of the covariates, while the other remains unchanged.

The model will also output the variance of the random intercepts for `patient_id`. This will give you a measure of the clustering effect of repeated measures - a high value indicates high correlation between measurements on the same patient (intra-patient variability), and an assessment of the intra-class correlation (ICC) will help to quantify this (though since you have a glmm, the ICC is not quite as straight forward as it would be if it was a (not generalised) linear model. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62770/calculating-icc-for-random-effects-logistic-regression) for details of computing the ICC for mixed effects models. To test whether there is in fact a clustering effect (whether intra-patient variability is zero), you can do a likelihood ratio test, or compare AIC values.

The second model:

```
glmer2 <- glmer(outcome~genotype+drug_concen+(drug_concen|patient ID), family="binomial", data=data1)
```

is the same as the first, but this time you are allowing each patient to have their own "slope" for the variable `drug_concen`.