# Calculating ICC for a beta-binomial GLMM

Tags: r, multilevel-analysis, glmm, intraclass-correlation, beta-binomial-distribution

I understand that ICC in binomial GLMMs with a logit link can be calculated [via R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/62770/calculating-icc-for-random-effects-logistic-regression/233458), where the residual deviance is `(pi ^ 2) / 3`. However, this is assuming that the scale factor of the distribution is equals to 1 (according to Hox et al., 2017)

Given this, I suspect that this method of calculating ICC would not be appropriate if used in the context of beta-binomial GLMM. If so, is there a way to calculate the ICC of a beta-binomial GLMM?

I am pretty new to the world of GLMMs(and stackexchange) so please do bear with me if I misunderstood anything!

**References**
Hox, J. J., Moerbeek, M., & van de Schoot, R. (2017). Multilevel Analysis: Techniques and Applications (3rd ed.). Routledge.